# Draw a horizontal line in Pine at trade entry

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

There is a simple script on Pine. When executing strategy.entry, I try to draw a horizontal line at the level of the trade entry price. The only way I found to get the trade entry price was strategy.opentrades.entry_price. But its data type cannot be used in hline and there are incomprehensible stories with an index, for example strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0) - displays the last closed trade, instead of just the last one (it doesn't matter if closed or not).

Does anyone have any idea how to draw a horizontal line at the entry price? The whole brain has already taken out to itself)

```
take_profit = input.float(0.7, title='Take-profit, %', step=0.1) / 100

open_order = false

if (high - low) / low * 100 <= 2.4
    open_order := true
    open_order

close_order = close >= strategy.position_avg_price + strategy.position_avg_price * take_profit
strategy.entry('buy', strategy.long, comment='Buy', when=open_order)
strategy.close('buy', comment='Profit', when=close_order)

plot(strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Pinescript so I don't know if there is a better way but I use these 2 lines of code and it works.

```
P_line  = strategy.position_avg_price

P_ep = plot(series=strategy.position_size != 0 ? P_line : na, color=color.new(color.white, 50), style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=1, title=' Price Line')
```